# Liferay Asset publisher: Add permission to specific users

Tags: permissions, liferay, assets, publisher

I have different Asset Publishers on different pages, for example: Assetpublisher1, Assetpublisher2, Assetpublisher3.. Now the User publisher1 should be able to create articles on Assetpublisher1 but not on Assetpublisher2 and Assetpublisher3. The User publisher2 should be able to create articles on Assetpublisher2 but not on Assetpublisher1 and Assetpublisher3..

How can i set the permissions to do that?

Liferay version: 6.2.3

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can't add permission for a specific user. You have to use role (roleAssetPublisher1, roleAssetPublihser2, etc) instead and assign user to role.

**EDIT:**
When you got role you have to add permissions on AssetPublisher on it (control panel > role) and in your case on each page assign the permission "configure portlet" to the role you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry i forgot to say that i have roles.. But how can i give one of this role the permission to add an article ?

Comment: The problem is, that there is no permission to add content :(

Comment: Permissions to add content are under Control panel > Role > Assign Permission > Web Content